# dataclass references the same object rather than initializing a new one

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass that looks like this (simplified and renamed):

```py
@dataclass
class SharedReference:
    bytes_io: BytesIO = BytesIO()
```

And I am running into an issue where I'm accidentally creating a shared reference so closing the IO stream for one instance closes it for all.

Looking at the ids, I see it is referencing the same memory id:

```py
shared = SharedReference()
print(shared.bytes_io)  # 0x7f...5e0
shared.bytes_io.close()

shared_2 = SharedReference() 
print(shared_2.bytes_io)  # 0x7f...5e0 (same id)
print(shared_2.bytes_io.closed) # True (got accidentally closed)
```

But this dataclass:

```
@dataclass
class SeparateReference:
    bytes_io: BytesIO = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.bytes_io = BytesIO()
```

works properly:

```py
separate = SeparateReference()
print(separate.bytes_io)  # 0x7f...d10
separate.bytes_io.close()

separate = SeparateReference() 
print(separate.bytes_io)  # 0x7f...680 (different id)
print(separate.bytes_io.closed)  # False (didn't get accidentally closed)
```

Why does the second work but not the first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was thinking that my first example was equivalent to the following code:

```py
class SeparateReference:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bytes_io = BytesIO()
```

but looking again at the [dataclass docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) it actually was giving me something like:

```py
class SharedReference:
    def __init__(self, bytes_io = BytesIO()):
        self.bytes_io = bytes_io
```

where `BytesIO()` is executed at the time of function definition rather than when an instance is created.

`field`'s `default_factory` argument also addresses this and would work to keep things separate (someone else mentioned this but then removed their answer):

```py
@dataclass
class SeparateReference:
    bytes_io: BytesIO = field(default_factory=BytesIO)
```